# Ruby Class Dir , how to select files from directory

Tags: ruby

I am currently selecting all .js files from a directory using the Dir class:

```
 Dir.glob("*.js") do |file_name|
```

In a Capistrano task, I would like to elect only 2 files from the directory ( index.js and staging.js or production.js according to the stage)  I tried :

```
Dir["index.js", "#{stage}.js"] do |file_name|
```

but I got an error on the do :

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
```

How should I write it ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the block form, you need to use `Dir.glob`; `Dir[]` doesn't work with a block. `Dir.glob` can take an array as its first argument:

```
Dir.glob(["index.js", "#{stage}.js"]) do |file_name|
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! I wasn't sure of it... ( no example in the doc...)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `each` method.

```
Dir["index.js", "#{stage}.js"].each do |file_name|
```

Comment: thanks ... using Dir.glob as stated by Jordan is in line with my block form usage